# How to remove style properties to other tags inside a paragraph and leave only one with style

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gty1996/xjudg8c1/1/) where I have inside paragraphs some other tags. Sometimes there are 2 and sometimes 3 of these tags. Each of them has a style property. What I want to achieve is get rid of the style properties from all of the tags and leave the style property to the last child only.

For example this one:

```
<p>
<em class="match js-match" style="background-color: rgb(228, 255, 0); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
  <em class="match js-match" style="background-color: rgb(98, 238, 120); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
    <em class="match js-match" style="background-color: rgb(255, 0, 76); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
      <anotation>Some text...</anotation>
    </em>
  </em>
</em>
</p>
```

should look like this:

```
<p>
<em class="match js-match" >
  <em class="match js-match">
    <em class="match js-match" style="background-color: rgb(255, 0, 76); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
      <anotation>Some text...</anotation>
    </em>
  </em>
</em>
</p>
```

With this jQuery code I can remove the style of all. But I don't want that. I want one of the `<em>` tags inside a `<p>` to retain the style.

```
document.onclick = function(){
  $("em.match.js-match").css({ 'background-color' : '', 'color' : '' });
};
```

I have looked into `first-child` or `last-child` or `nth-child` but couldn't do the job. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on with tag you want to remove styling from.

For the first tag

```
document.onclick = function(){
  $("p > em.match.js-match").css({ 'background-color' : '', 'color' : '' });
};
```

For the second tag

```
document.onclick = function(){
  $("p > em.match.js-match > em.match.js-match").css({ 'background-color' : '', 'color' : '' });
};
```

For the third tag

```
document.onclick = function(){
  $("p > em.match.js-match > em.match.js-match > em.match.js-match").css({ 'background-color' : '', 'color' : '' });
};
```

---

Edit: new answer for the updated question

```
$('p > em.match.js-match').each((index, element) => {
  const allEmTag = [element, ...$(element).find('em.match.js-match')];
  $(allEmTag).each((index, element) => {
    if (index !== allEmTag.length - 1) {
      $(element).css({ 'background-color' : '', 'color' : '' });
    }
  });
});

// or

$('p').each((index, pTag) => {
  const allEmTag = $(pTag).find('em.match.js-match');
  $(allEmTag).each((index, element) => {
    if (index !== allEmTag.length - 1) {
      $(element).css({ 'background-color' : '', 'color' : '' });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much Max. This helps a lot. Since you gave a more detailed answer I am gonna accept your answer. Even though Ameya was a few minutes earlier.

Comment: @ga1996 Thanks. BTW it would be simpler if you use different class name for different em tags, like `js-match-1` for the first tag, `js-match-2`for the second tag, etc.

Comment: hm.. I have another attribute inside the tag that has an id for each match like `data-id='match-1'` can this help?

Comment: @ga1996 Yeah. You can use `$("em[data-id='match-1']").css({ "background-color": "", color: "" })` instead. You can find out more about CSS selector here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors#Attribute_selectors

Comment: but the id doesn't start from 1 every time there is a new `<p>`. And actually in my real case removing styling manually from 2 tags inside a `<p>` isn't helping me, because sometimes there are 2 and sometimes there are 3 `<em>` tags inside a `<p>` as I have stated. The solution of Ameya R would help much better in the real life but if I could leave out only the last child. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: I would be easier to understand if you provide some code sample for situation you are talking about. So that I can give answer for each situations.

Comment: Thanks Max. Please, have a look at the jsfiddle I posted in my initial question. There are two `<p>`, one is with 3 em tags the other one with 2. Only the last child of the `em` tags should be left with the style properties. Imagine that I have more `<p>` with different number of `<em>` tags inside and only the last child should have the style property. I hope I was clear. Meanwhile I edited my initial question as well.

Comment: @ga1996 I have updated my answer. See if the new answer match what you want :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

you can try this also

```js
//$("em.match.js-match").css({ 'background-color' : '', 'color' : '' });
//$("em.match.js-match em.match.js-match").css({ 'background-color' : '', 'color' : '' });
$("em.match.js-match em.match.js-match em.match.js-match").css({ 'background-color' : '', 'color' : '' });
```

```css
em{
    width: 400px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 200px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <em class="match js-match" style="background-color: rgb(228, 255, 0); color: rgb(0, 0, 0)">
  <em class="match js-match" style="background-color: rgb(98, 238, 120); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
    <em class="match js-match" style="background-color: rgb(255, 0, 76); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
      <anotation>Some text...</anotation>
    </em>
  </em>
  </em>
</p>
```

Comment: I updated my initial question a bit. In the real life I need only the last child of the em tags to retain the style properties. If you could please look at the question once more?

Comment: is what I did and notice that the last `em` is nested inside others

Comment: but what when I have only 2 `em` tags or 4 `em` tags as I have already mentioned? I need a dynamic solution not like this "static". Ameya R solution works but only if it was the other way around (to skip only the last child not the first child).

Answer (score 1):

IF you queried only for ems that were children of ems I think it would skip the first child.
for eg.

```
$("em.match.js-match > em.match.js-match").css({ 'background-color' : '', 'color' : '' });
```

I'm not entirely sure of the syntax.

Comment: I have one question though to truly solve my problem. Can we do the opposite, query for parents and skip only the last child? If it works like this then that would be the ideal solution for me.

Comment: would you let me give you another answer to show you what I guess you're talking about